# Can I configure VMWare to always be in dual monitor mode?

Tags: multiple-monitors, vmware

I have a VM running Windows 7 on a host running Windows 10. We have to do all our development in the VM, so having it in multi-monitor mode is very useful.
Manually toggling it to multiple monitors works, but for some reason always reverts back to single monitor mode after being locked.

I tried manually specifying two monitors in the settings, but that doesn't seem to have much effect.

Is there any way to have it always in multi-monitor mode?

Answer (score 1):

This problem seems to date from 2013 :
[Multiple display guest reverts to single display after unlocking Windows 7 guest OS](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/456861).

It is described as :

> Running a Windows 7 client on two monitors and any time I wake up the client after it has turned off output to the monitors it reverts back to a single monitor. As others have described, it appears that the host still *thinks* it is displaying across two monitors.
>
> This thread began from a link to a similar problem in the beta forum. That original thread started in 2013 and looks like it addressed v8,9, and 10. It's now 4 years later and I'm running v12.5 and still have the same problem.

I don't think you should expect the problem to be addressed any time soon.

There is only one workaround listed in this post :

> I can resolve it by toggling the Cycle Multiple Monitors twice (once to turn it "off" and once to turn it back on),

Comment: Yeah, that's what I do, but the annoying thing is the windows tend to jump around and aren't properly full screen anymore. Quite a hassle.

Comment: All I can add is that you are not alone ... I have seen posts claiming this is better on VirtualBox, but have never used there that feature.